# Import operator into a function

Tags: python, function

I have this code :

```
if sudo_prob[a][b][0] in column[x] and x!=a:
    column[x].remove(sudo_prob[a][b][0])
if sudo_prob[a][b][0] in line[x] and x!=b:
    line[x].remove(sudo_prob[a][b][0])
if sudo_prob[a][b][0] in square[x] and (x%3!=b%3) and (a%3!=0+(x>2)+(x>5)):
    square[x].remove(sudo_prob[a][b][0])
```

It's the same operation aside from the variable call'd (line/column/square) and the condition (x!=a / x!=b...)

Is there a way to call a function which would take as parameters the variable & the condition ?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it? Note: http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractVariable.html

Answer (score 0):

Extract the common parts into a function:

```
def conditional_remove(list, element, condition):
    if condition and element in list:
        list.remove(element)

conditional_remove(column[x], sudo_prob[a][b][0], x != a)
conditional_remove(line[x], sudo_prob[a][b][0], x != b)
conditional_remove(square[x], sudo_prob[a][b][0], (x%3!=b%3) and (a%3!=0+(x>2)+(x>5)))
```